# How to pivot dictionaries contained within single pandas dataframe column into separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe that contains several id fields and another field which contains a dictionary of additional values that I need to tie to the id fields.I am trying to pivot this dictionary out and make each entry its own separate column within the existing dataframe

The below code does what I want, but it is very slow. Is there more efficient way of getting the same result?

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample table
a=[{'Feature1': 'aa1','Feature2': 'bb1','Feature3': 'cc2' },
 {'Feature1': 'aa2','Feature2': 'bb2', 'Feature3': 'abc' },
 {'Feature1': 'aa1','Feature2': 'cc1', 'Feature3': 'xyz' }
 ]
b=['num1','num2','num3']
c=['numa', 'numb', 'numc']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':b, 'id2':c, 'dic':a })

# Specify fields to construct the empty dataframe
cols = [
    'id1',
    'id2',
    'Feature1',
    'Feature2',
    'Feature3'
    ]
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

# Iterate through each row and grab values
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    id_records = list(row[['id1', 'id2']])
    other_vals = list(row['dic'].values())
    results.loc[idx] = id_records+other_vals
```

Edit: In my actual use case, some of the dictionaries are missing some of the keys. For example, the second row might not have a 'Feature2.' I would like this field to be null for that record. I'm not sure how to do this even in an inefficient way.

The code defines something closer to my actual data.

```
# Create sample table
a=[{'Feature1': 'aa1','Feature2': 'bb1','Feature3': 'cc2' },
 {'Feature1': 'aa2', 'Feature3': 'abc' },
 {'Feature1': 'aa1','Feature2': 'cc1', 'Feature3': 'xyz' }
 ]
b=['num1','num2','num3']
c=['numa', 'numb', 'numc']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':b, 'id2':c, 'dic':a })
```

Solution:

In addition to the below solution, my actual data was not being registered as a real dictionary. It was being registered as a string that looked like a dictionary. I had to convert it to a dictionary and then the below solution worked.

This is how I did that

```
import json

def convert_to_dict(string):
    return(json.loads(string))

df['fieldName'] = df.fieldName.apply(convert_to_dict)
```

Once you do this, Andy's solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: *On you updated sample. Missing `Feature` is construct as `NaN`*

```
df_final = df.drop('dic',1).join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.dic.to_dict(), 
                                                        orient='index'))

Out[1082]:
    id1   id2 Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
0  num1  numa      aa1      bb1      cc2
1  num2  numb      aa2      NaN      abc
2  num3  numc      aa1      cc1      xyz
```

---

Give this a try

```
df_final = df.drop('dic',1).join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.dic.to_dict(), 
                                                        orient='index'))

Out[1060]:
    id1   id2 Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
0  num1  numa      aa1      bb1      cc2
1  num2  numb      aa2      bb2      abc
2  num3  numc      aa1      cc1      xyz
```

---

Several other different ways:

from @Shubham Sharma:

```
df_final = df.drop('dic', 1).join(pd.DataFrame(df['dic'].tolist()))
```

from @anky:

```
df_final = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('dic').tolist()))
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: you may post it as an answer :)

Comment: @anky: yeah. `pop` is a nice way too :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: added. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you! This works for the example I posted. My actual case has differing numbers of fields in the dictionaries. So, the second row doesn't have a Feature2, so I think this is causing issues when I try to implement this solution on my actual problem. The right side of the join isn't being registered as separate columns.

Is there anyway to do the same thing if some of the dictionaries are missing some of the keys?

Comment: @JacobFerraiolo: On missing `Feature2`, the value will be `NaN`. It is the same as null. Check my updated answer

Comment: I thought my issue came from the empty fields, but it was actually a result of the dictionaries. They were not being registered as dictionaries in the column. They were strings with the same format as a dictionary, so I converted them to dictionaries and then your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobFerraiolo: I am glad you figure it out :)

Comment: In case anyone else has this same issue, I converted the pseudo-dictionary field to real dictionaries with json.loads() and apply()